# Function in validator, not controller giving me an undefined at 'lowerCase()'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, coffeescript

I have a form where I'm trying to ensure that case insensitivity is not a problem with an email validation.  I have an angular validation called `mustMatch` that does just what it states, it makes sure that the emails match index for index. However I also need to make sure that case is not an issue. So I ended up creating a secondary function called `matchCaseInsensitivity` and ultimately that is where I am having a problem because I decided the best way to fix this would be by adding the `tolowerCase()` filter.  When I did this, i was able to bypass my angular mustMatch error messages (which is good), but when I would hit a submit on the form, I would then run into a javascript problem in that `'tolowerCase()' is undefined`.

I think that the reason why i'm getting this error is because I have these built in a validator file, not a controller. (not sure if that is anything)

My front end looks like this. Notice the `'match-case-insensitive' => true` as my build for the solution

```
      %input-md{ type: "email", "ng-model" => "vm.form.email_confirmation", required: true, 'must-match' => 'register_form["vm-form-email"]', 'match-case-insensitive' => true, 'ng-hide' => 'vm.form.validated_email', autocapitalize: 'off' }
        Confirm email address
```

My mustMatch validation error message is

```
if attr.mustMatch    then addValidation 'mustMatch',    'This field must match the previous value.'
```

The actual function that triggers the mustMatch error message, I also have it bundled with the '`match-case-insensitive'` that I refer to in the front end.  This also is in a validation file, not the controller. (for what that is worth....i dunno). (mind you, it is in coffeeScript)

```
getMatchValue = ->
      match = matchGetter($scope)
      if (angular.isObject(match) and match.hasOwnProperty('$viewValue'))
        match = match.$viewValue
      match

    $scope.$watch getMatchValue, ->
      ctrl.$$parseAndValidate()
      return

    ctrl.$validators.mustMatch = ->

      match = getMatchValue()
      if $attrs.matchCaseInsensitive
        ctrl.$viewValue.toLowerCase() is match.toLowerCase()
      else
        ctrl.$viewValue is match

    return
```

I continue to get this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at r.$validators.mustMatch`. I have been stuck on this for over 2 days, and truthfully have no idea how to solve it. I would really be grateful if someone could take a look and see what they can do.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it's clear that either `ctrl.$viewValue` or `match` (or both) are `undefined`. Not sure what you want the expected behavior to be in that situation, but here is one possible way you could do it (I'm going to write this in JavaScript):

```
match = getMatchValue()

if (!(match && ctrl.$viewValue)) {
    return false
}

if ($attrs.matchCaseInsensitive) {
    return ctrl.$viewValue.toLowerCase() === match.toLowerCase()
}

return ctrl.$viewValue === match
```